# splitting values in []string in go

Tags: go

I am a novice in Go programming language.
I am writing a code to input from cli for client and pass the values to server for processing. both client and server are residing locally.

code :

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    text := gettext()
    fmt.Println(text)

    result := strings.Split(text, " ")

    for i := range result {

        fmt.Println(result[i])
    }

}

func gettext() []string {

    flag.Parse()
    text := flag.Args()

    if len(text) < 1 {

        fmt.Println("Please enter radius")

    }

    return text
}
```

when i run from command line its is giving me following error :cannot use text (type []string) as type string in argument to strings.Split

Basically i want to separately print values from []string .

Can you please let me know how to do it.
I tried using strings.split.

Thanks.

Comment: Split wants a string and you give it a string array according to the return type given for ``func gettext()``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to separate values by `" "`
The values already separated and your function `gettext` returns a **slice** of parameters.
Try this example:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    text := gettext()
    fmt.Println(text)

    for i := range text {
        fmt.Println(text[i])
    }
}

func gettext() []string {
    flag.Parse()
    text := flag.Args()

    if len(text) < 1 {
        fmt.Println("Please enter radius")
    }

    return text
}
```

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Args):

> `func Args() []string`
>   `Args` returns the non-flag command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

strings.Split() is for spliting a **string** value, not a string **array**. Your gettext() is returing a string array, not a string. So you dont need string.Split(). Simply use

```
for _, str := range text {
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```